# How to remove unused CSS on pingendo?

Tags: css, pingendo

I am currently using pingendo to make responsive landing pages. But I am wondering if there is a way to remove unused CSS codes on the output of the project? I can't remove it manually, because I get thousand result of unused CSS property. My landing page is very simple and I don't think the css output of the project are all needed. What to do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pingendo, but maybe this helps: https://addyosmani.com/blog/removing-unused-css/

Comment: Does it removes all unused css?

Comment: I think so. Not sure though.